# Insert New Row VBA Macro

Tags: excel, insert, vba

I want to insert a new row in MS Excel using a VBA macro and also modify the background color (i.e. Interior.ColorIndex) of specific cells in the new row.

I am using `ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert` to insert a new row below the active cell, but I am unsure how to change the background color of specific cells in the new row.

For example:

If I inserted a new row (i.e. row 4) I would like to change the background color of cell `B4` and `C4` to be grey.

Any help would be most appreciated!

Regards

Martin

Comment: What is the code you're using to insert the row and how are you triggering it?

Comment: ' Insert row below active cell
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert

Comment: I am triggering it from a custom icon from the Ribbon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do it:

```
Sub insertRowAndHighlightCells()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rw As Long

    With ActiveCell
        rw = .Row
        .Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
    End With

    Set rng = Rows(rw + 1)
    rng.Columns("B:C").Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)

End Sub
```

**Edit**

An even simpler version:

```
Sub insertRowAndHighlightCells()

    Dim rw As Long

    With ActiveCell
        rw = .Row
        .Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
    End With

    Rows(rw + 1).Columns("B:C").Interior.Color = RGB(191, 191, 191)

End Sub
```

Comment: Miqi180 your answer kicked ass! Thankyou so much :-)

Comment: Thx. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the activecell.offset(1,0) that you used to insert the row?

E.g.

```
Sub test()
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
    ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Row, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Row, 3).Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    'Alternatively:
    Dim colorRow as integer
    colorRow = ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Row 'The inserted row)
    ActiveSheet.Range("B" & colorRow & ":C" & colorRow).Interior.ColorIndex = 15

End Sub
```